# Battery recharge functionality broken due to short in AC adapter?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, laptop-repair

I have a problem recharging the battery of my netbook, an ASUS Eee PC 1025C.

Since last week the LED of the AC adapter doesn't light up when it is connected to the wall. The netbook won't turn on with the AC adapter plugged in (even if the battery is present). But I can turn it on using the battery alone.

To get rid of the problem I replaced the AC adapter with another one. Now I can turn on the netbook using AC power (with and without installed battery). But charging the battery no longer seems to work.

Moreover, if the other AC adapter is connected to the netbook - even if it is not connected to the wall - the LED of the adapter lights up.

What can be the reason for this? Do I have to replace the battery as well? Will this solve the problem?

Comment: Many new AC adapters feature switched mode power supply transformer which is easily damaged by power surges from lighting strikes. Furthermore, some adapters feature a control circuit which communicates with the computer's power management system. Your system may be damaged by a power surge. I recommend a BIOS update of your new computer along with any firmware software as well. Don't use the old adapter again, sounds fully broken, u'll prob ends up hurting the laptop.

Comment: Side note: Is your new adapter the exact same model? Brand new? Right country voltage? Just checking. Also try different wall plugs in the house.

Comment: Both adapters are for (different) ASUS Eee PCs. The replacement is some years older than the broken one. The original one has model number AD82000 (In: 100-240V (50-60Hz) 0.8A; Out: 19V 1.58A) and the replacement EXA0901XH (In: 100-240V (50-60Hz) 1.0A; Out: 19V 2.1A). Judging from the size I'd say both of them are switched-mode power supplies. They seem to have only two contacts, so I guess no control circuit!?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a short in the original charger. It could be in the charger or maybe the wire to the laptop is damaged. If not that, as @Pathfinder states in his comment, this may be the result of a power spike.

It is possible that whatever caused the original problem actually damaged the laptop so if your new power supply is the right kind, the laptop is probably a write-off I'm afraid.

Regarding the replacement power supply, all modern electrical and electronic equipment is pretty relaxed about input power levels. After all, they tend to be used all over the world and many parts of the world have very poor electrical services.

There are 3 possible figures to check on a power supply to make sure it is compatible with your laptop. The output voltage, output current (in amps) and the output power (in watts). You need 2 of the 3 values.

The **output voltage** should be **the same** as the original power brick though the system *might* still work on a lower voltage. That can't be guaranteed though. You don't want a higher voltage even though the laptop *would*, almost certainly tolerate it (up to a point).

The **output current** needs to be at least the same or **higher** than the original otherwise the laptop will not be able to get enough power.

You might see the output power in watts instead of the current. Again the power needs to be the same or higher than the original.

So in your case, the new power supply should indeed be fine.